# rails 3.2.2 (or 3.2.1) + Postgresql 9.1.3 + Ubuntu 11.10 Connection error

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am using PostgreSQL 9.1.3 (PostgreSQL 9.1.3 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc-4.6.real (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.1-9ubuntu3) 4.6.1, 64-bit) and rails either 3.2.2 or 3.2.1 on ubuntu 11.10.

Now, I can connect with below command with PostgreSQL

1. su postgres

   enter password and I can see postgres=#
2. I am placing below details in my config/database.yml and executing "**rails db**" it is **working fine.**

   `development:`

   ```
   adapter: postgresql
   encoding: utf8
   reconnect: false
   database: sample_app_db
   pool: 5
   username: postgres
   password: passwordhere
   host: localhost
   ```

I am using rvm to access my rails environment. but when I start server using "rails s" command and hit url with "http://localhost:3000", say - connection not establish.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

try this way,

```
sudo -u postgres createuser -D -P your-current-ubuntu-username
```

and

```
sudo -u postgres createdb -O your-current-ubuntu-username your-database
```

open up this file `/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/pg_hba.conf`

change this line only:

```
local   all             all                                     peer
```

to this:

```
local   all             all                                     md5
```

***Don't forget to restart the postgres server:***

```
sudo service postgresql restart
```

Now check, with this command

```
psql -d your-database -U your-current-ubuntu-username -W
```

it should work

This solutions works for `postgresql-9.1`, here is the way to install

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.1
```

Comment: For me, the helpful part of this answer was in changing pg_hba.conf. That was different from other posts I'd read.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to propose a slightly different approach which utilizes the file socket instead.

By allowing your *Ubuntu user* access to the database, everything should work without special connection parameters.

**In the Ubuntu command line:**

`createuser -U postgres your-current-ubuntu-username`

see the [Manpage of createuser](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/en/man1/createuser.1.html) for details.

**In your database.yml:**

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: sample-app_development
  pool: 5
  username: your-current-ubuntu-username
  password:
```

Comment: createuser -U postgres railpg
Shall the new role be a superuser? (y/n) y
createuser: could not connect to database postgres: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "postgres"

Comment: Side note: When this is correctly set up, you can easily inspect your databases with pgAdmin III (`sudo apt-get install pgadmin3`) by providing this path as 'Server' option: **/var/run/postgresql** (if PG is installed in default locations / i.e. via apt-get).

Comment: works fine - when I did first "su postgres" then execute createuser command

Comment: Good. When at `su postgres` you may omit the **-U** flag like so: `createuser your-current-ubuntu-username`. In case of problems you can get rid of a user by issueing: `dropuser username-to-be-deleted`

Comment: After following steps, its say  password authentication failed for user "your-current-ubuntu-username"

Comment: Where does it say that? Note that **no password** is required as this is 'peer authentication' now (instead of 'password authentication').