# Setting up postgres for rails production on VPS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I'm currently setting up a rails application on a VPS and the process went rather well up until now. There seems to be a problem with rails connecting to my production database.

What I tried so far:
Creating the "test" user and the production database "nn_production":

```
$ sudo -u postgres createuser -D -P test
$ sudo -u postgres createdb -O test nn_production;

\l gives:
     Name      |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |   Access privileges
---------------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------
 nn_production | test     | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |
```

Furthermore in `/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/pg_hba.conf` 
[from related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9797640/rails-3-2-2-or-3-2-1-postgresql-9-1-3-ubuntu-11-10-connection-error)

I changed this line only:

```
local   all             all                                     peer
```

to this:

```
local   all             all                                     md5
```

I tried the following and that works.

```
$ psql -d nn_production -U test -W
```

Here is my database.yml

```
production:
adapter: postgresql
encoding: unicode
database: nn_production
min_messages: ERROR
pool: 5
host: localhost
username: test
password: test
```

I used capistrano and I'm in /u/apps/nn/current

Now when I try:

```
$ rake RAILS_ENV=production db:schema:load
```

I get the infamous

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished
```

I'd be very thankful for any pointers. If theres some vital information missing just shout at me.

Edit: `cat /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.2-main.log`

```
2013-03-05 14:32:55 CET LOG:  received fast shutdown request
2013-03-05 14:32:55 CET LOG:  aborting any active transactions
2013-03-05 14:32:55 CET LOG:  autovacuum launcher shutting down
2013-03-05 14:32:55 CET LOG:  shutting down
2013-03-05 14:32:55 CET LOG:  database system is shut down
2013-03-05 14:32:56 CET LOG:  database system was shut down at 2013-03-05 14:32:55 CET
2013-03-05 14:32:56 CET LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
2013-03-05 14:32:56 CET LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2013-03-05 14:32:57 CET LOG:  incomplete startup packet
```

Setup:

- Ubuntu 12.10
- rvm
- ruby 1.9.3
- rails version 3.2.12
- pg gem 0.14.1

Comment: What does your postgresql log say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel like such an idiot. The indentation in database.yaml is significant. Total hours wasted: 8.